# Custom module causes an AJAX error

Tags: paragraphs, 9

I created a custom module which creates a content type (*FAQs*) with a paragraph field whose type is *FAQ Item* (with 2 fields, title and text).

After installing the module, I have a new content type as expected.

I add this new content type (which works), but when I want to add more paragraphs, I get this error.

> [image: error]

**edit start**

```
↵An AJAX HTTP error occurred.↵HTTP Result Code: 200↵Debugging information follows.↵Path: /node/add/faq?ajax_form=1↵StatusText: OK↵ResponseText:
```

**edit end**

Is there any missing configuration the module should provide?

The YAML files are inside faq/config/optional. They have been created from the UI on another site and exported.

**edit 2 start**

My module files and structure

[image: img1]

*.info.yml* file I have basic info link name, type, description, core_version_requirement and package.

*.libraries.yml* Am importing a JS file, inside "src-js"

*.module* is empty, without any php code.

*.routing.yml* also have basic stuff:

```
faq:
path: '/faqs'
defaults:
  _controller: 'Drupal\faq\Controller\GetFaqController::getFaq'
  _title: 'FAQs Page'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

Inside config-optional folder I have my YML to create content type, fields and paragraph. Those .yml files I exported from another website where I create all of this and deleted "uuid" line.

[image: img2]

Then in my controller I also have basic stuff (for now).

```
class GetFaqController extends ControllerBase {
public function getFaq() {
    
    echo '<h1>FAQs</h1>';

    return [
        '#title' => 'test'
    ];
}
```

}

This is my module structure/files.

Have very basic configs, that's why I am a bit lost with this error and what I search online I found same error but it is not related.

It seems something is missing with paragraphs and ajax request to add more.

**edit 2 end**

**edit 3 start**

I have created another module, this new module only creates a paragraph type with 2 fields (title and text), then I add manually this paragraph to "Article" content type and I get same error.

Another thing I have notice, in a clean drupal site with paragrpahs module installed, when I create a paragraph type manually via backoffice and then add it to any content type works correctly, when I install my module all paragraphs fields stop working and give this error.

If I uninstall my module and delete paragraph type created by my module, other paragraphs type start working again.

Here a repository of my custom module if someone want to test.

https://gitlab.com/drase15/custom-module

**edit 3 end**

Comment: It would help if the error message were completely quoted, not shown in a screenshot.

Comment: The Ajax error message is often not really helpful. Try taking a look at Reports > recent log messages under `/admin/reports/dblog` for some first debugging info

Comment: @Hudri I don't get any message under "recent log messages", paragraphs module use ajax when adds another item, but the ajax is not working (for some reason idk), it is nothing to do with "server side"/php, I think is kind of backoffice "client side" :/

Comment: Since you are developing, you'd definitely switch off JS/CSS aggregation and cache. And without seeing the custom module and the exact code you used to create the content type and paragraph types it's probably more like finding the needle in a haystack, sorry.

Comment: hey @leymannx I have disabled JS/CSS aggregation and cache. Also added more information about my module structure and files

Comment: Try without the direct “ echo '<h1>FAQs</h1>';” in your controller. Also check if it is ok in a different browser, eg not chrome. Any change?

Comment: hi @DavidThomas have tried but still not working, also I create another module, but a little more simple, only create a paragraph type and fields, then add manually this paragraph to "Article" and got same error

Comment: This question can never be answered because it's too vague. You could have an error in the code that creates the fields or paragraphs, the routing YAML above is indented improperly and the controller has an echo in it for starters. Disable all these custom modules and clear the cache and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This is certainly weird https://gitlab.com/drase15/custom-module/-/blob/master/src/js/expand_and_collapse.js but I don't see anything loading that JS file anyway. You need to start by disabling this module, and seeing if the error still occurs. If it does, it could be a contributed module.

Comment: hey, if I disable the custom module everything works great, if I enable custom module error occur. JS file is being called on .libraries.yml file. I start cleaning my first module to try to find the error, at this moment my module only create a paragraph type with 2 fields based on .yml files under config-optional folder

Comment: It must be that Javascript file. You need to write it to conform to how Drupal in JS is added. You also don't need that .module file.

Comment: hey @Kevin I know I don't need .module file, but like I said, I start to cleaning up my module and leave only the .yml files to test it out

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I just need to change a folder name -.-
Changed from "optional" to "install", after that everything works as expected.

Thanks for your help.